# mybatis mapping multiple OUT to java object

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

Having problems mapping procedure params. Error:

```
Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00201: identifier 'getAnswer' must be declared\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n\r\n### The error may exist in ..retrieveInfoMapper.xml\r\n### The error may involve ..retrieveInfo-Inline\r\n### The error occurred while setting parameters\r\n### SQL: { CALL getAnswer(    ?,    ?   )   }\r\n### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00201: identifier 'getAnswer' must be declared\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n\n; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00201: identifier 'getAnswer' must be declared\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n
```

Procedure:

```
    CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE getAnswer(request IN VARCHAR2,result OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
               a     VARCHAR2(60);
BEGIN
    SELECT a.b
    INTO   result
    FROM   ..;

END;
```

mybatis conf:

```
<mapper namespace="..InfoMapper">


    <select id="retrieveInfo" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
        { CALL getAnswer(
            #{request, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN},
            #{result, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT}
        )
        }
    </select>

</mapper>
```

And i call it like this:

```
        HashMap<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("request", "test");
        params.put("result", null);
        infoMapper.retrieveInfo(params);
```

Is there something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this error, you should modify your procedure to declare the variable `partner_code`

Comment: sorry, there was mistake in procedure. please see update

Comment: 1) Check your spelling and declaration of the referenced name. 
2) If the referenced item is indeed declared but you don't have privileges to refer to that item, for security reasons, you will be notified only that the item is not declared.

Comment: 3) If the referenced item is indeed declared and you believe that you have privileges to refer to that item, check the privileges; if the privileges were granted only via a role, then this is expected and documented behavior. Stored objects (packages, procedures, functions, triggers, views) run in the security domain of the object owner with no roles enabled except PUBLIC. Again, you will be notified only that the item was not declared.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that i was using wrong data source.